# htaccess multiple 301 redirects

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am looking for some help with setting up some redirect rules in my htaccess file. I have switched the site to run on Codeigniter, and basically all pages ending in .php, now just have that ending removed, ie `www.mysite.com/foo/bar.php` is now `www.mysite.com/foo/bar`

I have tried just listing the redirects like so:

```
Redirect 301 http://mysite.com/foo/bar.php http://mysite.com/foo/bar
Redirect 301 http://mysite.com/foo/bar/bar.php http://mysite.com/foo/bar/bar
Redirect 301 http://mysite.com/foo/bar/foo.php http://mysite.com/foo/bar/foo
```

etc (About 12 rules needed). Bizarrely, it works for the first rule but not the others? Am I not listing them correctly? Everything I've read tells me this is how it is to be written. So what am I doing wrong?

**Additional Information that may be relevant:**

My htaccess file already contains the following code (for removing 'index.php' from urls):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Not sure if it matters if this is placed before or after the rewrites? Also, the site in question is an addon domain. I am not entirely sure whether these rewrites should be placed in the .htaccess file in the public folder of the master site, or in the addon domain's subdirectory? (I've tried both, with the same result).

Help please! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to turn on the logging feature of the server - this will allow you to see "what is sees and how it interprets it".

Comment: Hi, Floris, I am able to access some error logs through cpanel. I can see now that some errors have been thrown. They seem to take the format: "htaccess: Redirect takes two or three arguments, an optional status, then document to be redirected and destination URL"

Answer (score 6):

Sorry, I've just solved this. I removed the base URL from each rule and now it works. ie:

```
Redirect 301 /foo/bar.php /foo/bar
```

Instead of:

```
Redirect 301 http://mysite.com/foo/bar.php http://mysite.com/foo/bar
```

Not entrirely sure why... need to read up.

Comment: Happy you were able to solve it yourself. Thanks for posting the solution.